# "Access is protected" error loading Lucee admin page using coldbox

Tags: coldfusion, lucee, coldbox, commandbox

I'm tring to start a coldbox app and when I do the Lucee admin page doesn't work. The coldbox main page comes up fine but when I try to go to lucee admin 127.0.0.1:60235/lucee/admin/web.cfm  I get an error
Lucee 5.4.3.2 Error (security)  Message Access is protected
Detail  to access the configuration without a password, you need to change the access to [open] in the Server Administrator
Stacktrace The Error Occurred in /admin/web.cfm: line 174

here is what I did in commandbox
[create app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rpg8F.jpg)

[create app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzSPn.jpg)

```
`CommandBox:testapp2> start server`
```

I also tried changing APPNAME=testapp2  I also tried putting the password.txt in \lucee-5.4.3.2\WEB-INF\lucee-server\context folder   what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Mike, try to install this module:

```
box install lucee-password-util
```

Then add these entries to .env file.

```
# Lucee Admin
CFCONFIG_ADMINPASSWORD=mypassword
CFCONFIG_WEB_ADMINPASSWORD=mypassword
CFCONFIG_SERVER_ADMINPASSWORD=mypassword
```

Then stop and start your server again. Now you should be able to log in with **mypassword**.